# Check file in and preserve the last modified by

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, list-item

Is it possible to check in a file as another user? The reason I ask is that I perform some updates to a list item including the modified by. I would like to preserve the modified by

Comment: Are you using a script or codebehind to perform the update to the list item?  Otherwise, it is not possible to preserve the Modified By if the action is done on the UI.

Comment: I'm using CSOM to do the update. I'm using the checkout and checkin to prevent multiple versions of the file. When I go to checkin it has me as the last modified.